# How to link a page to back button in browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, back

In a web page I have made a Tabbed Menu with three different pages .It works fine until user press the back button , this makes the control to move among these tabbed pages . I want to link a page to the back Button in browser . I have searched google most of people say it is not possible . I have tried using  window.onbeforeunload but this also not works .Please help how to do this or any work around?

Comment: Where should the back button take you to ?

Comment: Some example ? What you'd tried ? Or fiddle of the Tabbed Menu.

Comment: To my peferable link.... like the last page!!

Comment: You can do pretty much anything you want with the back button on modern browsers.  It can even be used as a button in a game (e.g. WiiU gamepad B button in the browser works like a back button, but can be repurposed).

Comment: Set a cookie in the next page, check onload if cookie is set - clear the cookie and use location.replace(URL) to not break the back button

Comment: @fakerainbrigand - kidding right?

Comment: @mplungjan, nope!  You can just use the history API to keep pushing a new item onto the history stack when the back button is pressed, and also handle it in some other way :-)

Comment: @mplungjan how can I do the cookie technique ....I am new to this dont know much about cookies!!!]

Comment: There is a site called Stackexchange you can search for [javascript cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+cookie)

Comment: @fakerainbrigand ah - yes. Not supported until IE10 so I did not consider that. Why do you not post it with a link to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=history) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Answer (score 0):

you can to this by this method

```
onClick="history.go(-1);return true;

<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">
```

or

```
<script>
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.back()
  }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="goBack()">
```

Comment: as per your comment "To my peferable link.... like the last page!!" it will take you to the last page

Comment: No actually I want this method to be called at BROWSER's BACK BUTTON click(button on the left corner)!!!!